# max cache size is reached while playing media player

Tags: android

I am using media player to play list of songs.But after playing for several times now my logcat says that prepare() cannot be done because of max size of cache has been reached.Even when I stopped the application and run again but it showing same error.

My question is how I can handle the error ,that is how i can free the cache memory after playing a single songs or while closing my application.

Second qestion is mediaplayer continue to stream even i stop my application .How it can be stoped.

Thank you
chandan kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i uninstall the application and then I reinstall it .Now it is working fine.Earliear it was not woking because of overrun of loop and memory got fulled and that is why it was not able to prepare but now now after uninstalling and reinstalling ai working fine.